# Filter out the strings in series of files

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

i have a group of files with path names in a text file name "files.txt" like below

files.txt contains these files:

```
/usr/local/test1.txt
/usr/local/test2.txt
/usr/local/bin/grr.txt
/usr/local/oracle/test4.txt
```

now i have to grep(filter) values for the strings name "PackageName" and "ProcedureName" for all these files into a output.txt file

for ex : all the above files has the below content,now i want the values for PackageName and ProcedureName as in the format "XXbin/process" in an outputfile.

```
 <property name="PackageName" value="XXbin"/>
  <property name="ProcedureName" value="process"/>
```

tried:

```
find ${direct} -name "*.jca" -exec awk "/ && /PackageName/ && /ProcedureName/' {} \; >> out.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a suprious `/ &&` at the start of your awk command and you have double quotes at the start of the awk script but single quotes at the end of the script and you're using `&&` when you want `||`.

In any case, keep it simple:

```
find "$direct" -name "*.jca" -print |
xargs awk '/(Package|Procedure)Name/'
```

Comment: Hi Ed,i have to read each file from files.txt and just print the value of Package and Procdeure name not entire string.

Comment: Isn't that the question you asked at http://stackoverflow.com/q/32726286/1745001?