# grep values and re-arranging the file

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, cut

hi i have a file name test.txt

```
    (standard input):8:      <property name="ProcedureName" value="abc"/>
(standard input):7:         <property name="PackageName" value="123abc"/>
(standard input):8:         <property name="ProcedureName" value="bac"/>
(standard input):7:      <property name="PackageName" value="bac123"/>
(standard input):8:      <property name="ProcedureName" value="cde"/>
(standard input):7:      <property name="PackageName" value="cd123"/>
(standard input):8:      <property name="ProcedureName" value="b4u"/>
(standard input):7:      <property name="PackageName" value="b4u234"/>
```

i have to grep only values of packagename and procdeurename from this file in the follwing format: into an o/p file

```
abc/123abc
bac/bac123
cde/cd123
b4u/b4u234
```

tried cut and awk but couldnt get that

Comment: Show us your attempts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this `awk`:

```
awk -F'"' 'NR%2{p1=$4;next} {print p1 "/" $4}'
```

**Test:**

```
$ awk -F'"' 'NR%2{p1=$4;next} {print p1 "/" $4}' file
abc/123abc
bac/bac123
cde/cd123
b4u/b4u234
```

Comment: This also works: `awk -F\" -v OFS=/ '{printf "%s%s", $4, NR%2?OFS:ORS}' file`

Comment: @EdMorton, Thank you. Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

My first attempt (and the one I'd actually recommend) was the same as @sat's so I deleted it and here's a different approach in case it's useful in some other context:

```
$ awk -F'"' '{n2v[$2]=$4} !(NR%2){print n2v["ProcedureName"] "/" n2v["PackageName"] }' file
abc/123abc
bac/bac123
cde/cd123
b4u/b4u234
```

`n2v` means `name2value`, an array name I often use for the type of application where we have name to value mappings in the input file.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU grep and paste:

```
grep -oP '"\K[^"]*(?="/)' file | paste -d / - -
```

Output:

```
abc/123abc
bac/bac123
cde/cd123
b4u/b4u234
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly, although I would have used the pattern `'(?<=value=").*?(?=")'`

Comment: @glennjackman: Yes, I found your thoughts yesterday [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32724834/3776858).

Answer (score 1):

`awk` should be able to do this for you:

```
awk -F'"' 'BEGIN { OFS="/" } $2=="ProcedureName"{procedureName=$4} $2=="PackageName" { print procedureName,$4 }' yourfilename
```

This will use double-quote as the seperator. It tests for the string "ProcedureName" in position 2 and stores position 4 in the variable `procedureName`. Then if it finds "PackageName" in position 2, it prints out the stored `procedureName` and the stuff from position 4. And it uses backslash as the OutputFieldSeperator.

Technically you could pipe your `grep` to this, but `awk` can just do the search itself, which is what I've written up here.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s#.*value="\([^"]*\)".*value="\([^"]*\)".*#\1/\2#' file
```

Read two lines at a time and extract the values between double quotes preceeded by the literal `value=`.

Another slightly shorter version using a backreference in the LHS and `-r` option to make the regexp easier to read:

```
sed -r 'N;s#.*(value=")([^"]*)".*\1([^"]*)".*#\2/\3#' file
```

Yet another way, using the hold space and substitution:

```
sed -r 's/.*"(.*)".*/\1/;h;N;s//\1/;H;g;s#\n#/#' file
```

Extracts the last value between double quotes in two successive lines and re-arranges the results to the required string.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `awk` and `grep` solutions.

```
sed -rn 's|.*"([^"]*)"/>|\1|p' xml | pr -2ats/
```